# Pre-built Library Targets

Tags: shared-libraries, static-libraries, bazel

Is there a way to specify a Bazel target like with `cc_library` but for an existing pre-built static or shared library.

I couldn't find a reference to such a rule in the Bazel documentation.

Comment: Do you mean something like [java_import](https://bazel.build/versions/master/docs/be/java.html#java_import) but for C++? That is, do you have a `.so` file and you want to link to it from your own `cc_library`?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `cc_library` itself, just put `.so` files in `cc_library.srcs`. See [the docs](https://bazel.build/versions/master/docs/be/c-cpp.html#cc_library.srcs).

Answer (score 1):

The cc_import rule does precisely what you're asking and I believe a little bit cleaner than the accepted answer.